# shiny modal window does not accept js and css

Tags: javascript, html, css, r, shiny

So my Shiny app displays code. I want to have formatted code displayed so I use the highlight js library. I got this to work outside the modal window, but not inside it. The `modalDialog` function does not seem to accept my css and js input.

The code-chunk that works, without a modal window:

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    includeScript("/Users/stani/GitHub/bamlss.vis/inst/srcjs/highlight.pack.js"),
    includeCSS("/Users/stani/GitHub/bamlss.vis/inst/srcjs/default.css"),
    HTML('<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>'),
    tags$pre(tags$code('
                       for (i in 1:10) {
                       print(i)
                       }'))
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {}
)
```

Output looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gp4t0.png), we can see that formatting works.

However, when I use this code to display a modal window, it doesn't work:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    actionButton("show", "Show modal dialog")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$show, {
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Important message",
        # Include JS, CSS for syntax highlighting
        includeScript("/Users/stani/GitHub/bamlss.vis/inst/srcjs/highlight.pack.js"),
        includeCSS("/Users/stani/GitHub/bamlss.vis/inst/srcjs/default.css"),
        HTML('<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>'),
        tags$pre(tags$code('
for (i in 1:10) {
  print(i)
}'))
      ))
    })
  }
)
```

Instead, the output looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjmEP.png). We can see that the code is displayed but not formatted. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the timing of reading the js script was wrong. It has to be called in the general UI. In case anyone stumbles upon the same problem, here is my solution:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    includeCSS("/Users/stani/GitHub/bamlss.vis/inst/srcjs/default.css"),
    includeScript("/Users/stani/GitHub/bamlss.vis/inst/srcjs/highlight.pack.js"),
    actionButton("show", "Show modal dialog")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$show, {
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Important message",
        # Include JS, CSS for syntax highlighting
        tags$pre(tags$code('
                           for (i in 1:10) {
                           print(i)
                           }')),
        HTML('<script>$("pre code").each(function(i, block) {
          hljs.highlightBlock(block);
        });</script>')
      ))
    })
  }
)
```